# Error while loading shared libraries after installing a program

Tags: rhel, software-installation, compiling, yum

I was installing [rfc5766-turn-server](http://code.google.com/p/rfc5766-turn-server/downloads/list).
But it fails to launch with an error:

`error while loading shared libraries: libevent_core-2.0.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Here's a copy-paste of how I did the installation:

```
$ cd /var/tmp;
wget https://github.com/downloads/libevent/libevent/libevent-2.0.21-stable.tar.gz; tar xvfz libevent-2.0.21-stable.tar.gz; cd libevent-2.0.21-stable; ./configure; make; make install;
wget http://rfc5766-turn-server.googlecode.com/files/turnserver-1.8.6.3.tar.gz ; tar xvfz turnserver-1.8.6.3.tar.gz; cd turnserver-1.8.6.3; ./configure; make; make install;
/var/tmp/turnserver-1.8.6.3/bin/turnserver;
```

I tried this, but it didn't help (same error):

```
$ ln -s /usr/local/lib/libevent-2.0.so.5 /usr/lib64/libevent-2.0.so.5;
/var/tmp/turnserver-1.8.6.3/bin/turnserver ;
```

**EDIT:** (without changes if i run as below it runs it, but when i test with client it does not show any kind of logs that TURN is hitting or reached by client)

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/local/lib/; 
PATH="bin:../bin:../../bin:${PATH}" turnserver -L 176.34.x.x -a -b /usr/local/etc/turnuserdb.conf -f -r 176.34.x.x
1371111272: RFC 5389/5766/5780/6062/6156 STUN/TURN Server, version Citrix-1.8.6.3 'Black Dow'
1371111272: Config file found: /usr/local/etc/turnserver.conf
1371111272: Listener address to use: 176.34.x.x
1371111272: Config file found: /usr/local/etc/turnserver.conf
1371111272: WARNING: cannot find certificate file: turn_server_cert.pem (1)
1371111272: WARNING: cannot start TLS and DTLS listeners because certificate file is not set properly
1371111272: WARNING: cannot find private key file: turn_server_pkey.pem (1)
1371111272: WARNING: cannot start TLS and DTLS listeners because private key file is not set properly
1371111272: Relay address to use: 176.34.x.x
1371111272: IO method (listener thread): epoll
1371111272: WARNING: I cannot start alternative services of RFC 5780 because only one IP address is provided
1371111272: IO method: epoll
1371111272: IPv4. UDP listener opened on : 0.0.0.0:0
1371111272: IPv4. TCP listener opened on : 0.0.0.0:39227
1371111272: IO method (auth thread): epoll
1371111272: IO method (relay thread): epoll
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the obvious question: is that library installed?

Also, is it installed *for the right architecture*? (E.g. a 32-bit executable requires a 32-bit library, a 64-bit executable requires a 64-bit library.)

If you just added a library to a directory in the system library path, you'll need to run [`ldconfig`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ldconfig) as root. There's a cache of installed libraries, and `ldconfig` rebuilds that cache. If a library is present in a directory but not in the cache, it's not going to be used.

I see you added the library to `/usr/local/lib`. Most distributions include it in the default library path, but Red Hat doesn't. Add it to `/etc/ld.so.conf` then run `ldconfig`.

Run `ldd /path/to/excecutable` to see where an executable is finding its libraries. When a library is not found, `strace /path/to/executable` will tell you where the program is looking for it.

Comment: what ever shown above installation, without changeing anything if i do this it runs the application but it could be that still its not running correctly. e.g: `[root@ip-10-59-143-73 stund]# export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/local/lib/; PATH="bin:../bin:../../bin:${PATH}" turnserver -L 176.34.x.x -a -b /usr/local/etc/turnuserdb.conf -f -r 176.34.x.x`

Comment: Please see above EDIT Section.

Comment: @YumYumYum So the program now runs, but doesn't behave correctly. That's a completely different question, not about shared libraries but about rfc5766-turn-server. Ask it separately.